# pdfmake: Custom Fonts not render as expected

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I tried to make custom fonts in my own language, Khmer.

Expected:

[image: selection_024]

Rendered:

[image: selection_023]

I don't really know what I missed. Really appreciate for suggestion and idea.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define your custom font as the default font in the document definition, too?

```
    var dd = {
        content: [...],
        styles: {...},
        defaultStyle: {
            font: 'Sunshiney'
        }
    };
```

Comment: sure, I did.
That why it show the characters but the problem may as @devongovett said here: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/332#issuecomment-113962680

Answer (score 0):

pdfmaker is a javascript lib, that might need to see with Khmum browser that seems to use Javascript function to render the text for Khmer characters.